# UIViews buttons inside a scrollview not triggering IBAction

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

I have a horizontal scrollview with pagination enabled so each page will show a distinct xib view. Some xib views have buttons in them that linked to IBAction. I declare the IBAction in each xib's class. Everything seems and looks good the buttons show clicking effects and all, but the IBAction isn't fired? 
Here is a code sample:

```
let clockView: ClockViewController = ClockViewController(nibName: "ClockViewController", bundle: nil)

    let carView: CarViewController = CarViewController(nibName: "CarViewController", bundle: nil)

    scrollview.addSubview(clockView.view)

    carView.view.frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.width

    scrollview.addSubview(carView.view)
```

clockView and carView both have buttons in them and the buttons are linked to IBActions declared in ClockViewController.swift and CarViewController.swift respectively.

Here how one of the views look like. I'm not adding UIViewController in the xib, I'm only using a UIView. I'm guessing this could be part of the problem but I can't use UIViewController as subview because it gave an error.
[image]

[image]

[image]
Any help is appreciated,

Comment: What is `filesOwner` ?

Comment: the fileOwner is the same xib class, and I updated the question to show that, thanks.

Comment: I think your problem is that you are putting `CarView` in a local variable so it will be released when e function exits. Try putting it in an instance variable/property

Comment: Wow that was exactly the problem! I declared carView inside viewDidLoad() The problem solved when I declared it out of it in the class. Thank you very much dude :) you should make it an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are declaring `carView` as a local variable, so it will be released once the function exits as there is nothing to hold a strong reference.  The view elements themselves are referenced by the scrollview, so they aren't released but there will no longer be a view controller instance to process the events.

If you change `carView` and `clockView` to be properties then a strong reference will be held.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems that you are using ViewControllers inside ViewControllers. If you'd like to do this via storyboard, you'll have to use a containerView and place the ViewController within this containerView using the embed segue that it comes with.

If you'd like to do this programmatically, you'll have to add child viewcontrollers to the parent viewcontroller that emcompasses these child View Controllers that you have which are carView and clockView.

P.S. it's a bit confusing that you are calling your view controller `carView`, perhaps `CarViewController` is less confusing :)

Comment: Thank you, sorry for the confusion. You're right I can't use UIViewController inside another UIViewController and it gave me an error, so I'm not using UIViewController in the xib, i'm only using UIView.